# Using Iterators

Tags: java, oop

I have a very basic question in mind. An Iterator is an interface so to create an object we will need to create a class that implements Iterator and then create an object for the same. But when i saw the use of iterator it confused me as we are referencing an interface directly without having a class that implements it. for example :

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
   map.put("1", "One");
   map.put("2", "Two");
   Iterator i = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

how come we have an object of an Interface!!

Comment: And what about: `Map map = new HashMap();`?

Comment: @AlexStybaev it will get you a new `HashMap` instance that can be accessed like any `Map`.

Comment: @DerMike i know it. That is just the same as for Iterator, isn't it? Just an implementation of `Iterator` interface.

Comment: I think the problem is that @Amit doesn't see class which implements `Iterator` returned by `iterator` method. This class is inner class in `HashMap` and is not public. [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.HashIterator) it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterator is a interface, but `map.entrySet().iterator()` returns an object which implements the Iterator interface.

Comment: To add: here is real class which used by `HashMap`. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.HashIterator

Answer (score 0):

You'll get some implementation from that call. You just cannot assume more than the things that are enforced (and documented) be the iterator interface. Look for "anonymous inner class".